# Having trouble with display colums from 4 tables MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model as below and want to display items from 4 different table.

```
public class AuctionViewer
{
 public int AuctionId { get; set; }
public string ProductName { get; set; }
public int Price { get; set; }
public DateTime  startTime { get; set; }
public DateTime  EndTime { get; set; }
public string Category { get; set; }
public int ExpectedHit { get; set; }
public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my controller code below.

```
 public ActionResult Index()
       {
      MightyMouseContainer ctx = new MightyMouseContainer();

       var  NewList = new AuctionViewer
             { 
                     from CT in ctx.Categories 
                     join PD in ctx.Items on CT.Category_ID equals PD.Category_ID
                     join AU in ctx.Auction_Schedule on PD.Item_ID equals AU.Item_ID 
                     join ST in ctx.Status on AU.Status_ID equals ST.Status1
                     orderby AU.Auction_ID
                     select new
                     {
                       AuctionId = AU.Auction_ID, 
                       ProductName = PD.Item_name,
                       Price= PD.Item_Value,
                       startTime = AU.Start_Time,
                       EndTime = AU.End_Time,
                       Category = CT.Category_Description,
                       Status = ST.Description
                    };


    }

        return View(NewList);
    }
```

I wonder why is giving errors. please advise. I have been on this for quite a while and realized that I need some help to move on. I will appreciate prompt response in other to move forward. Thanks

Comment: What error do you get? Please post the full error message!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your view accepts a model of `IEnumerable<AuctionViewer>`, you should change the select to return the strongly typed collection, e.g.:

```
var  NewList = from CT in ctx.Categories 
                     join PD in ctx.Items on CT.Category_ID equals PD.Category_ID
                     join AU in ctx.Auction_Schedule on PD.Item_ID equals AU.Item_ID 
                     join ST in ctx.Status on AU.Status_ID equals ST.Status1
                     orderby AU.Auction_ID
                     select new AuctionViewer
                     {
                       AuctionId = AU.Auction_ID, 
                       ProductName = PD.Item_name,
                       Price= PD.Item_Value,
                       startTime = AU.Start_Time,
                       EndTime = AU.End_Time,
                       Category = CT.Category_Description,
                       Status = ST.Description
                    };

return View(NewList);
```

**Edit** From your second error message, it seems that the view expects a `List<AuctionViewer>`. You can change the controller method to materialize the IQueryable as a `List` as follows:

```
var  NewList = (from CT in ctx.Categories 
                     join PD in ctx.Items on CT.Category_ID equals PD.Category_ID
                     join AU in ctx.Auction_Schedule on PD.Item_ID equals AU.Item_ID 
                     join ST in ctx.Status on AU.Status_ID equals ST.Status1
                     orderby AU.Auction_ID
                     select new AuctionViewer
                     {
                       AuctionId = AU.Auction_ID, 
                       ProductName = PD.Item_name,
                       Price= PD.Item_Value,
                       startTime = AU.Start_Time,
                       EndTime = AU.End_Time,
                       Category = CT.Category_Description,
                       Status = ST.Description
                    }).ToList();

return View(NewList);
```

Comment: Error 15 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dream.Areas.Admin.Models.AuctionViewer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\Dream\Dream\Areas\Admin\Controllers\AuctionScheduleController.cs 39 24 Dream
still have same error

Comment: @user1656779 Can you show your model for Controller/Index.cshtml / /aspx please? Specifically the 'at' model directive at the top.

Comment: Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Dream.Areas.Admin.Models.AuctionViewer>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Dream.Areas.Admin.Models.AuctionViewer>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) D:\Dream\Dream\Areas\Admin\Models\AuctionModel.cs 39 43 Dream    The SELECT is underline with the above message

Comment: OK, this one is a bit easier to deal with - I'll edit my answer.